# Catch a click event without binding event

Tags: jquery, events, hyperlink, bind

I want to intercept certain link clicks on my page and call them via ajax, preventing the default action.

I have this problem: I'm not able to do the binding, because lots of links are being loaded to the page constantly, so I would have to run $('a').bind('click') all the time - on each ajax load. And I can't put 'onclick' function on all links, because it will take too much time refactoring all layouts.

Is it possible to set one global listener, that will catch the `Click` event and see if that was a click on a 'a' element?

I think it might be possible doing through the `Onbeforeunload` window object, something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

 //here shold be some function that detects original event name ('click') and element that was clicked, so I could make an ajax call on that url instead of going to that url

};
```

Can I catch the event name and what's more important the path name of the location the browser is going to?

Comment: Unless you explicitely bind the `click` event to an `a`-tag, it will be handled as classical anchor link and therefore does not fire any events javascript-wise. `onbeforeunload` will not give you any reference; also at that point the anchor click will already have been triggered.

Comment: :( that's what I though, but I hoped that there might be some way...

Comment: may be its possible to get some usefull via window.addEventListener('click') ?

Comment: Another option would be to (monitor changes to the DOM (mutation events). See http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
        //Do something
    });
});
```

This will 'bind' your function on all `a` elements when a `click` happens.
This also ensures that it works for elements created so far, and for elements created in the future.

More information: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**UPDATE:** Also to prevent default action, use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I like this approach. So does this really apply to elements that are added later on during 'runtime' so to speak?

Comment: @SquareCat Yes, I use this code myself to use it on all `a` elements on initial loading, **and** on the `a` elements that are being loaded in via AJAX.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for enlightening me, i thought one needs to explicitly bind if further elements are added later on.

Comment: It works fine. In event.target.baseURI I can see required url and then decide what I want to do - prevent default and load contnt by ajax or go throgh

Comment: @ProstoTrader It seems like you are using `jquery` (as suggested by the tags). It would then be advised to also really use it: You can get the `href` tag of the `a`, with: `$(this).attr("href")`.

Comment: Or to get absolute path, use `this.href`. BTW, you could filter to target only external links, not local ones e.g used for internal navigation: `$(document).on("click", "a[href]:not([href^=#])", function(event) {...})`

Answer (score 0):

The .on() method of jquery should be preferred from now on.

The other options are .bind(), .delegate() and the now deprecated .live() methods.

The .on() method and their corresponding  .bind(), .live() and .delegate() are given below:

```
$( "#members li a" ).on( "click", function( e ) {} );  
$( "#members li a" ).bind( "click", function( e ) {} );
```

// Live

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#members li a", function( e ) {} );  
$( "#members li a" ).live( "click", function( e ) {} );
```

// Delegate

```
$( "#members" ).on( "click", "li a", function( e ) {} );  
$( "#members" ).delegate( "li a", "click", function( e ) {} );
```